# Losing form data

Tags: php, forms, back

I want to use **back option** on php without losing the **form data**.

I've tried this way;

```
if ($username==""){
    echo 'Please fill. <input type="button" value="Back" onClick="history.back()">';
} else{
    $doaction;
}
```

And this way;

```
$url= $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if ($username==""){
    echo "Please fill.";
    header("refresh: 2; url=$url");
}
else{
    $doaction;
}
```

On both ways I lose my data.  How can I make this better?

Comment: What do you mean you lose data? That if you post to a page and hit the back button that it all the form fields are empty?

Comment: There's no need to go back and forth, just include your form again and / or post to the same page and pre-fill the form values if a post is made and the conditions are not met.

Comment: @putvande: My guess is he has a `<form>` and when he goes back to the page, it's empty.  He wants the data entered to be there when he goes back.

Comment: You cannot use JavaScript style location change in HTTP header location.. use it like `header('Location: ' . $url);`

Comment: It's normal. I think u want to resolve this problem using only JS.

Comment: @putvande yes i mean that.

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes you're right :)

Comment: @DanFromGermany but how can i tell the user "please fill here"

Comment: @MaciejCzyżewski no man. the way isn't important. i just dont want to loose the filled data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me and using [`ob_start();`](http://www.php.net/ob_start) (in PHP below) needs to be included, otherwise it will throw an error, such as:

> PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started)

Use the following exactly as shown, then modify to suit later.

Using **[Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)** is a way to achieve this. Each field will re-appear in the input boxes, if they were filled.

### HTML form (form.php)

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<form method="post" action="submitted.php">
    <p>
        <label for='name'>Your Name:</label>
        <br>
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : '' ?>">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for='name'>Email:</label>
        <br>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['email']) ? $_SESSION['email'] : '' ?>">
    </p>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <br>
</form>
```

### PHP (submitted.php)

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];

$url= $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

// use this one below, if you want to check more than one field
// if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['email']) ){

if (empty($_POST['username'])){
echo "Fill in all fields.";
header("refresh: 2; url=$url");
}
else{
echo "OK, redirecting back to show fields are showing, or not.";
header("refresh: 2; url=$url");
}
```

Comment: You're quite welcome :) Have a great day. @MadGemini

Comment: Hi man! I've tried to reset the form today. And the html one doesnt works. I think i have to destroy the session for to do that. But i have a diffirent sesion also in the same page. What must i do? :))

Comment: Hi. Well you could create a logout page, with `session_destroy();` inside of it, if that's an option, and/or if you want to unset a particular session name, use `unset($_SESSION['session_name']);` --- `session_name` can be anything you want it to be. @MadGemini

Comment: Yes :) Thanks again. I've done like this: 
`<a href="clean.php">Clean</a>`
On clean.php:
`unset($_SESSION['subject']);
header ("location: form.php");`

Comment: Great, glad to hear it worked out for you :) Cheers! @MadGemini and you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach reloads the formular, so the webserver will send a clean form to the client. If you want a prefilled form you will have to use a PHP script which knows the formerly filled in values and creates a prefilled form.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have used, (assuming you have a form further up) there is no data being passed between the pages because nothing is telling the script to transfer the data between that page and it's destination.

In your first example, `history.back()` simply tells the browser to go back to the last page viewed before the current one. In your second example, your header line essentially just tells the browser to go back to the previous page after two seconds.

To keep data between page transfers, without any further knowledge of what you're doing, I would suggest using JavaScript to fetch your form data and pass it into a URL used in a window.location call (forming a GET request with your form data in it), OR by using javascript to set a cookie containing the data input before you tell the browser to switch page.

In the first solution, you could then use php's $_GET global to access your form data.

In the second solution, you could use javascript to re-populate the form on page load (or at will)